# Magento : Thumbs not Changing Main Image on Mobile View

Tags: magento-1, image, mobile, thumbnail

When I view site in mobile , below width 770px, the more views thumbs stop working.

Not so fussed about zoom, the problem is thumbs are clickable but don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the `app.js` file and there's some code about **min-width 770px** but I couldn't work out how to stop it.

So I added this to my `jquery` file which somehow stops the conflict on mobiles - even tho there's no conflict on desktop over 770px.

```
var jq14 = jQuery.noConflict(true); 

(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
```